# DBPedia SparQL select Players of Team

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, dbpedia

i'm trying to select any active players of an soccer Team.

for example i have selected the football team for Austria

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
    ?club a dbo:SoccerClub ;
          dbo:ground ?grounds . 
    ?grounds  dbo:location ?country.
    FILTER(?country = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Austria>)
}
```

The 
[result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDGy2.png)
 seems very well

Now I'm trying to get all active players for one soccer team/club.

for example:http://dbpedia.org/resource/FC_Red_Bull_Salzburg

so I have tried the following query

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
?player dbpedia:currentclub ?teamName.
OPTIONAL {?teamName dbpedia:ground ?ground}.
OPTIONAL {?grounds  dbo:location ?country}.
OPTIONAL {?player dbpedia:cityofbirth ?city}.
OPTIONAL {?player dbpedia:dateOfBirth ?dob}.
Filter(?country = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Austria>)
Filter(?teamName = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/FC_Red_Bull_Salzburg>)
}
```

but unfortuality the query returns no results.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: And from where do you have the property `dbpedia:currentclub`? Did you simply invent this property? You can only use properties that exist in the dataset.

Comment: yes I know it's wrong, but I'm not sure which one is the right property to check if the player plays currently in the team. 

And I have tried a lots of suggestions but nothing returns the correct soloution.

Comment: DBpedia is probably a bad dataset for time related information. The query to start is `PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?player
WHERE {
?careerStation dbo:team ?teamName ;
dbo:currentMember ?player .
Filter(?teamName = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/FC_Red_Bull_Salzburg>)
}` time-bound information is bound to so-called careerstations which are basically intermediate nodes.

Comment: The "better" source would be Wikidata for this kind of data

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes I guess so too WikiData is for this kind of data better.

Comment: [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) typically lags Wikipedia by 6-18 months. [DBpedia-Live](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) typically lags Wikipedia by minutes.